# Add Function Import not available for function

Tags: stored-procedures, entity-framework-4, user-defined-functions, database-first

I've added a function in my database and I wanted it to be callable in my code.  For stored procedures I've right clicked on the SP and selected Add Function Import in Model Browser to achieve this, but this option is not available for my function.  What can I do to import the function?

Comment: Did you update your model from the database after adding the stored procedure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Database functions are not available for Function import. Function import works only with stored procedures. You must manually [create stub function](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2008/10/08/edm-and-store-functions-exposed-in-linq.aspx) and mark it with `EdmFunction` attribute for database function available in your model.

Comment: Table-valued functions seem to import just fine for me.

Comment: @bostIT: Yes, they were added in later EF version.

Comment: Scaler funtions does not get imported as of now May 2018