# EF6 Model First Can't import function

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a model first database model in Entity Framework 6 and I've been trying to import a scalar function to use for sorting; however, while EF does find the function, it's unable to import it for some reason.

There are no error messages or anything, the function added from the database simply doesn't show up in the Add Function Import window whereas it does show up in the database Store in the Model Browser.

[image: Function import]

[image: Empty dropdown]

[image: Model Browser]

Comment: "it's unable to import": how do you know? Are you getting an error or something else?

Comment: No error message. The function simply doesn't show up in the function import window (see how the drop-down is empty?) even though it does show up in the Store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after an additional 30 minutes of searching on top of the 2 hours in the beginning, I've found this answer:

[Add Function Import not available for function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11191254/add-function-import-not-available-for-function)

In addition to this:

[Entity Framework scalar function mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12393291/1974352)